# How to preserve a websocket connection on ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, websocket

I have an ASP.NET Core application that needs to communicate with the browser through websockets.

The server is configured as follows :

```
        var webSocketOptions = new WebSocketOptions()
        {
            KeepAliveInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120),
        };                   

        app.UseWebSockets(webSocketOptions);
        app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            if (context.Request.Path == "/ws")
            {                    
                if (context.WebSockets.IsWebSocketRequest)
                {
                    using (var  WS = await context.WebSockets.AcceptWebSocketAsync())
                    {
                        // do some stuff or even nothing
                    }   // <<<<<<<<<<<<<< connection dies here                                                   
                }
                else
                {
                    context.Response.StatusCode = 400;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                await next();
            }
        });
```

The connection works properly with the browser, but at the end of the following block, the connection automatically dies.

```
using (var  WS = await context.WebSockets.AcceptWebSocketAsync())
{
    // do some stuff or even nothing
}   // <<<<<<<<<<<<<< connection dies here
```

There is no exception in my code, but still the connection dies. I guess this is normal since the variable WS is destroyed after `using`.

I would like to know please how can I make a websocket connection last and not destroyed immediately after the server gets a connection request.

Also, I see that with this code

```
WS = await context.WebSockets.AcceptWebSocketAsync()
```

a new web socket is created for every connection attempt, even if it's coming from the same client that had previously connected. Is possible to change that behavior please ?

Thanks,
Cheers

Comment: Not to be "that guy", but have you considered SignalR? It takes all the BS out of WS and just works with little to no effort.

Comment: Yes? You'll need some kind of loop to read / write messages. When your middleware returns, the connection will be closed.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman do you hava any idea/example how to do that please ? thanks

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=acceptwebsocketasync+example